# How to force the method for a formtastic form to be put?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have something like

```
semantic_form_for @whatever, :url => whatever_url
```

which generates a from with

```
method="post"
```

I need it to be put, I've already tried:

```
semantic_form_for @whatever, :url => whatever_url, :html => {:method => "put"}
```

and

```
semantic_form_for @whatever, :url => whatever_url, :html => {:method => :put}
```

and

```
semantic_form_for @whatever, :url => whatever_url, :html_args => {:method => :put}
```

with no effect. Any ideas how it's done?

Comment: Is @whatever already existing in the database?

Comment: Why do you want/need to *force* it? Normally specifying the method isn't necessary because it is handled automatically.

Comment: Heikki, no, @whatever is a new record.

Comment: Did you try my solution? Only want to know if it works..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it generating a form that looks something like this?

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
...
```

If so, then it's probably still creating a PUT request.  Rails determines the POST, PUT or DELETE request by using the _method attribute instead.  The best way to verify that this is working is to check your logs to see that a PUT request is coming through.  You can also force this to happen by adding a hidden attribute to your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

Answer (score 15):

See http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/formtastic/0.9.10/Formtastic/SemanticFormHelper
and try:

```
  <% semantic_form_for :whatever, @whatever :url => posts_path, :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```